# What programming languages would be best suitable to create an e-commerce site from scratch? Or is it just better to use a cms like Wordpress?

Tags: web, web-applications, e-commerce

The e-commerce site would include a booking system also and other variables other than just selling and buying goods.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, there is no simple answer, but, that also means more variety of languages to choose from, you can do anything with almost every programming language, but, each one has its strong points and weak points; In my opinion, heading for the most popular is the best choice to opt to, given a few reasons:

1. It is easier to find tutorials and answers to your questions, as they will most likely have big communities.
2. They're popular for a reason, as they are most likely best suited for web development.

Some of these languages are Javascript, Python & PHP — for quite a few reasons, but, as to my personal opinion, I think JS dominates the web development market.

First, to start-off, JS or Javascript is a high-level, medium difficulty language, a scripting language(it is also, OOP(Object-Oriented-Programming) language, but, it is really not, as it is just an illusion.); Javascript is the dynamic life of the web, Javascript does anything from animations, events and et cetera to HTTP requests, fetching, I/O intensive work and it is the most used language in the web!
Javascript has some sugary syntax, so, it is not hard to read and also, it can do absolutely anything from OOP to Dynamic programming and on top of that, it has the 2nd largest community as of now.

But, there is one flaw with it, it is a single-threaded language, so, it only works as one bartender in a whole bar with thousands of people, but, that bartender works at the speed of light, it doesn't wait until the drink becomes ready, but, rather queue up orders and hand them out in the same order, but, it will only take orders and not execute them until the first one does and the second one, the third one and so on, so forth; therefore, it is prone to be blocked and if that happens, your whole site becomes unresponsive, but, that could be fixed pretty easily and with a few good practices, you will be safe; so, don't get discouraged by this, JS is really powerful and one con against all of these pros isn't really significant, but rather, negligible.

Python or PY is more suited for process-intensive stuff (i.e. calculations), so, if your site has some math in it, then, Python would be the choice to go for; also, python is rather good in managing data, analyzing it and et cetera, that is why it is being used in almost any data-science infrastructure; also, Python is very user-friendly, very easy to learn and read, also, it has the biggest community that you can find. (Also, Python has the shortest syntax that you can find.)

This was both languages in a nutshell, but, you have to know that Python isn't really good at optimizing hardware, so, it will drain the hardware, but, JS (and its back-end framework — Node.js) are very good at RAM optimization and ALSO, JS is said to be 75 times faster than Python, so, there is that.

Both languages have their back-end frameworks like Node.js and Django(for PY), but, Python can't be used in the front-end, which is a down-side, but, not really a big deal.

Also, you have to know that you can now, code with any programming language on the web, using something called Web Assembly, it changes any programming language into JS, so, it could be understood by the browser, but, that is a very broad topic and I don't suggest using Web Assembly, as you have to learn new things and it is only good for a couple of small things and E-commerce ain't one of them.

So, to end this off, JS & PY are the pretty strong and best choices to make when it comes to E-commerce, but, you'll probably need a few more things like query languages for databases(like SQL) and an actual database like MongoDB or Firebase, but, that choice is up to you.

ALSO NOTE: JS has front-end frameworks & Libraries like React.js(A view library) and Angular.js(A framework) and Vue.js which is best suited for light-weight projects.

Hopefully, I helped you to make a choice about your site, and please, don't use CMS as you'll be supporting the CMS community which is trying to kill the programming community (which will never happen), and also, you can't call yourself a developer if you use them only and don't code at all. (Yes, they are easier and save time, but, not the best nor optimal solution as they restrict you.)

"Programming isn't about what you know; it's about what you can figure out.” - Chris Pine.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on "how" you want to make it and "when" you want it, and as a programming language just pick the one you're familiar with and can do the stuff for you. Don't choose a low-level language like C because it will be really painful to make a website using it.